# After a normal day at the market

Tags: logical-deduction

(This is a variation of the [fox, goose and bag of beans](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fox,_goose_and_bag_of_beans_puzzle) puzzle)

After a normal day at the market, you are bringing home a wolf, a goat, a cabbage, a mouse and a moose.

You come across a bridge which will support your weight along with the weight of either two non-moose things or one moose.

If you leave these animals alone together, the following interactions can take place:

- the wolf will eat the goat
- the moose will kill the wolf because it doesn't like wolves
- the cabbage will attack the goat, for murdering its people
- the mouse and the moose will eat the cabbage, because it's delicious

The animals have to cross with you, else they will fall into the water below.

**What things, in what order, do you have to cross the bridge with so no violence occurs and all of them make it to the other side?**

Comment: I don't know why I laughed hard for this line: *the cabbage will attack the goat, for murdering it's people*.

Comment: How can cabbage attack goat? Won't goat eat said cabbage first?

Comment: @Lau Wan The cabbage has a higher power level

Comment: @Unlambder goat = 12 kg  cabbage = 0.1 kg :/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe this works:

> First trip: Wolf, since that conflicts with both moose and goat (and we can't take both of them), and cabbage (which conflicts with mouse and moose).
> Then we take the moose over, and return the wolf and cabbage.
> Then, take mouse and goat over.
> Finally, return (empty) and take back wolf and cabbage.

Systematic notation with E indicating moose (elk), since M is for mouse, . indicating the farmer and | indicating the river:

> ```
> WGCME.|
>  G ME |W C.
>  G ME.|W C
>  G M  |W C E.
> WGCM .|    E
> W C   | G ME.
> W C  .| G ME
>       |WGCME.
> ```